# Ruby - Class methods

Tags: ruby, methods

I'm a newbie starting to learn Ruby. I have created this code, however it returns it keeps returning `NoMethodError, undefined method new`. What am i doing wrong here?

```
class Pessoa
  attr_accessor :nome, :idade, :altura

  @@lista = []

  def self.lista
    @@lista
  end

  def initialize(nome, idade, altura)
    pessoa = self.new
    pessoa.nome = nome
    pessoa.idade = idade
    pessoa.altura = altura
    @@lista << self
  end
end

pessoa1 = Pessoa.new("Joao",13,2)
pessoa2 = Pessoa.new("Alfredo",15,1)
puts Pessoa.lista.inspect
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

During the execution of `Pessoa#initialize` `self` holds an instance of the class `Pessoa`. Therefore, you're trying to call `new` on an instance of the class `Pessoa`.
This is impossible, because `new` is a *instance method* of class `Class`: you're correctly calling it on the `Pessoa` class in the last lines, but you can't call it on an instance (such as `pessoa1` or `pessoa2`, or the `self` in the `Pessoa#initialize` method), because none of them **is a Class**, and therefore don't define the `new` method.

The correct code would be:

```
class Pessoa
  attr_accessor :nome, :idade, :altura

  @@lista = []

  def self.lista
    @@lista
  end

  def initialize(nome, idade, altura)
    @nome = nome
    @idade = idade
    @altura = altura
    @@lista << self
  end
end

pessoa1 = Pessoa.new("Joao",13,2)
pessoa2 = Pessoa.new("Alfredo",15,1)
puts Pessoa.lista.inspect
```

Answer (score 3):

That `pessoa = self.new` is your problem. `initialize` is called on an object that's already been created to set up its initial state, so

1. `self` doesn't have a `new` method there (because it isn't a class)
2. There's no point in creating an object in there and assigning it to the local variable `pessoa`, because it will just disappear after the method is finished

I think what you want is:

```
def initialize(nome, idade, altura)
  @nome = nome
  @idade = idade
  @altura = altura
  @@lista << self
end
```